# python post request with cookies asp.net

Tags: python, asp.net, screen-scraping

Please help. I'm trying to create a POST request on an .asp site that requires cookies, but the way I handle them seems not to return anything. Read through some questions of similar topic but can't find the _SessionID cookie some are referring to. Please help me formulate this POST request so it works.

**Headers**

```
:authority: safer.fmcsa.dot.gov
:method: POST
:path: /query.asp
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: max-age=0
content-length: 85
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=ywxszihqlu1yciwe5z5gm4qt; etype=au; ASPSESSIONIDQECTCDRB=KGFOBHBBLKCBKBFIAPEBMIHJ; ASPSESSIONIDQGARCDRA=LKEDBAOBMOMDNGBNBFEMMIPB; ASPSESSIONIDSEBQCBSB=DAMJMNKCNJKHCMDCIJBPKEHD; ASPSESSIONIDCEQRADQC=EIEJCDLBHHCCKHCNJNIMHDKA; ASPSESSIONIDAESTCBQC=KPDPJNHCLOBJENEHPNIFKJLH; LI_carrier=67449; ASPSESSIONIDAGSQADRC=CPIBAKEDDPNFCIPLIGLOKKLA; ASPSESSIONIDAERTDBQD=FMKFHJJAJKNIGCBCCFJFCMNF; AWSALB=Xc7OAuZUmx6vgE5l9NaawsH8oBWjy6eZ3B62kw2rZ5HieoRlMu4SSmVVcaPJPcPjp1fVt9U/T9FaRflgNHwtzmsK4X4e+y+yoGArTfgpb75NWo/ilAek0Qk/sFYI; AWSALBCORS=Xc7OAuZUmx6vgE5l9NaawsH8oBWjy6eZ3B62kw2rZ5HieoRlMu4SSmVVcaPJPcPjp1fVt9U/T9FaRflgNHwtzmsK4X4e+y+yoGArTfgpb75NWo/ilAek0Qk/sFYI
origin: https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov
referer: https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/CompanySnapshot.aspx
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36
```

**Form Data**

```
searchtype: ANY
query_type: queryCarrierSnapshot
query_param: USDOT
query_string: 2300842
```

**My Code So Far**

```
def checkDOT():
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate,max-age=0,private',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'origin': 'https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov',
        'referer': 'https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/CompanySnapshot.aspx'
    }

    s = requests.Session()

    data = {
        'searchtype': 'ANY',
        'query_type': 'queryCarrierSnapshot',
        'query_param': 'USDOT',
        'query_string': '2300842'
    }
    params = (
        ('pageNumber', '0'),
        ('itemsPerPage', '15'),
    )

    url = 'https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/CompanySnapshot.aspx'
    response = s.get(url, headers=headers, data=data, params=params)

    if response:
        print(response.content)

    else:
        print("This did not work")
```

Answer (score 0):

get requests dont use data parameter, and your code is requests.get,is that right?
I can get a html page with:

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0',
}
url = 'https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/CompanySnapshot.aspx'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: Correct but I need to submit the data to the form and get data back from. In that case how do I submit the form found there with:

 data = {
        'searchtype': 'ANY',
        'query_type': 'queryCarrierSnapshot',
        'query_param': 'USDOT',
        'query_string': '2300842'
    }

?